# Careers Search Bug

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

I was trying to find telecomute jobs with the C# tag on the careers site.  So I put "C#" in the search and checked the telecommute checkbox and browsed the results

Later I viewwd all telecommute jobs and saw a job being offered by "[TrackAbout](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/8241/senior-web-mobile-net-software-engineer-trackabout)".  This job has the C# tag but does not show in the search results for "C#" and telecommute.  Is this a bug?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, this should be [resolved](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs#/?searchTerm=c%23&location=&range=20&telecommute=true).