# Careers search not yielding proper results

Tags: support, status-bydesign, tags, jobs, search

I tried to search for remote jobs with the tag "python" so the url from it is: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=python&allowsremote=True

That returns 14 matching jobs, but this one for example is not in that search: https://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/84538/senior-software-developer-rackspace-the-sharp1-managed

Tried the same with "ruby" and remote: http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?searchTerm=ruby&allowsremote=true resulting in 20 jobs but again, not listing this: https://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/102186/software-engineer-delivery-digitalocean

I found it was supposed to be a fixed bug: [Careers Search Bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/94527/careers-search-bug) but apparently they are hiding information or the bug is still there and it's a concerning bug.

[edit] Adding screen capture of "python" search result:

[image]

**[edit 2] Using a vpn to browse the site like I am inside the US I get 70 results from the first link. So yeah, results are filtered regionally, sadly.**

Comment: Hm, I actually get 70 results from the first link, including the one you mentioned was excluded. I don't know why that is, though.

Comment: @TimStone that is weird. I added a screen capture and I am only getting 14 jobs. Could it be that results are being filtered regionally ?

Comment: Results are filtered according to targeting regions and countries set by the employer. @PepperoniPizza what region (continent or country) are you in, that'll help to narrow down whether this is a bug or by-design

Answer (score 4):

Those jobs you link to are targeted by the employer to only be displayed in the **North America** region. This means that the job isn't shown in ads or on the job board unless we geo-locate you to North America.

Judging from your login IP it looks like you aren't located in that region which is why you're not seeing these jobs in the search.

We do this primarily to limit the number of applicants an employer gets that they may not be able to act upon because of visa restrictions.

That said, we are making changes to perform better matching in the job board and allowing you to specify locations of interest is one of the key matching parameters that we use. I'll discuss internally whether it makes sense to change the region targeting from geo-location to user-specified location instead.

Comment: That makes sense. Although it would be nice perhaps to display something like "US-remote", because I found those links in a Google search but then it's no specified inside Careers that is only supposed to be for US based people and avoid other people to lose time applying for those.